# Google play does not display App Version

Tags: android, version-numbering

we are currently using androidquery to determine whether a customer's app is up2date. This does not work of late, the returned version is [null](https://androidquery.appspot.com/api/market?app=de.ergovia.stepfolio). It does work with different [apps](https://androidquery.appspot.com/api/market?app=org.ligi.fast) though. The "Current Version" of our app [is not displayed on Google Play either](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.ergovia.stepfolio) (even after clicking on "Read More"). That may be the culprit. We are using two apks with different "version codes" but identical "version names" to address arm and x86 tablets separately. I am expexting the "version name" (android:versionName — A string value that represents the release version of the application code, as it should be shown to users.) to be shown in the store entry. Has anyone a similar setup and knows why the "current version" has vanished from the Google Play page?

Thx in advance

Comment: which version code are you trying to obtain? the arm of the x86? and more importantly, how do you expect google play to know what version you are after?

Comment: App version will be available in "Read More" section in Google Play App.

Comment: I am trying to obtain the version name. Even if androidquery is trying to obtain the version code, I would expect a different result that "null". Plus I definitely expect the version name to be shown in the play store.

Comment: We finally gave up and now keep track of the released version ourself.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue and the same config, 2 apks for both arm and x86 architectures, for one of my apps. On the other hand I've another app with universal apk and the Current Version field is in place on the page on Google Play.

So, it's very possible that this issue is related to the configuration with multiple apks. Besides, there is no specific trigger to show the Current Version in Google Play Console.